# Query created by multiple group by queries taking hours to run

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not a database person, and am one of the only people in my office that can understand any SQL or ACCESS.  Therefore I have become the go to.

I have a table that has over 30 million records and am trying to create a query that uses several group by queries to create.  Only problem is it takes hours to run and I'm not sure how to improve its performance.  Here is an example of the first query:

```
SELECT      dbo.Characteristics.TagCode, dbo.Characteristics.[Release Date/Time],
            dbo.All_data.HD, MIN(dbo.All_data.[Date/Time]) AS [MinOfDate/Time], 
            MAX(dbo.All_data.[Date/Time]) AS [MaxOfDate/Time],
            dbo.Detection_Sites.Site, dbo.Detection_Sites.Description,
            DATEDIFF(second, 
                     dbo.Characteristics.[Release Date/Time],
                     MIN(dbo.All_data.[Date/Time])
                    ) AS TravelTime_101
FROM          dbo.All_data
INNER JOIN    dbo.Detection_Sites
           ON    dbo.All_data.HD = dbo.Detection_Sites.[Hydrophone Number]
INNER JOIN    dbo.Characteristics
           ON    dbo.All_data.Tagcode = dbo.Characteristics.TagCode
GROUP BY dbo.Characteristics.TagCode, dbo.Characteristics.[Release Date/Time], 
         dbo.All_data.HD, dbo.Detection_Sites.Site, 
         dbo.Detection_Sites.Description
HAVING   (dbo.All_data.HD = 101)
```

All the other group by queries are similar, only difference is the HD in HAVING       (dbo.All_data.HD = 101) is different.  I am then trying to pull them all together to create one output.

```
SELECT  dbo.Characteristics.TagCode, dbo.Characteristics.Release, 
        dbo.Characteristics.[Release Date/Time], 
        dbo.Mayfield_HD101_First_Last_Detections.[MinOfDate/Time] AS HD101_First_Detection, 
        dbo.Mayfield_HD101_First_Last_Detections.TravelTime_101, 
        dbo.Mayfield_HD101_First_Last_Detections.[MaxOfDate/Time] AS HD101_Last_Detection, 
        dbo.Mayfield_HD102_First_Last_Detections.[MinOfDate/Time] AS HD102_First_Detection, 
        dbo.Mayfield_HD102_First_Last_Detections.TravelTime_102, 
        dbo.Mayfield_HD102_First_Last_Detections.[MaxOfDate/Time] AS HD102_Last_Detection, 
        dbo.Mayfield_HD203_First_Last_Detections.[MinOfDate/Time] AS HD203_First_Detection, 
        dbo.Mayfield_HD203_First_Last_Detections.TravelTime_203, 
        dbo.Mayfield_HD203_First_Last_Detections.[MaxOfDate/Time] AS HD203_Last_Detection, 
        dbo.Recollected_MDC_HD204_Last_Detection.[MaxOfDate/Time] AS HD204_Recollected_Last_Detection, 
        dbo.Recollected_MDC_HD204_Last_Detection.Recollected AS Recollected_Travel_Time, 
        dbo.Barrier_First_Last_Detections.[MinOfDate/Time] AS BD_First_Detection, dbo.Barrier_First_Last_Detections.TravelTime_BD, 
        dbo.Barrier_First_Last_Detections.[MaxOfDate/Time] AS BD_Last_Detection, 
        dbo.Hatchery_First_Last_Detections.[MinOfDate/Time] AS TH_First_Detection, dbo.Hatchery_First_Last_Detections.TravelTime_TH, 
        dbo.Hatchery_First_Last_Detections.[MaxOfDate/Time] AS TH_Last_Detection, dbo.Characteristics.FishStatus, dbo.Characteristics.DNCO, 
        dbo.Characteristics.Upstream, dbo.Characteristics.Tagger
  FROM dbo.Characteristics
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Mayfield_HD203_First_Last_Detections 
           ON  dbo.Characteristics.TagCode = dbo.Mayfield_HD203_First_Last_Detections.TagCode
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Barrier_First_Last_Detections 
           ON dbo.Characteristics.TagCode = dbo.Barrier_First_Last_Detections.TagCode 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Recollected_MDC_HD204_Last_Detection
           ON  dbo.Characteristics.TagCode = dbo.Recollected_MDC_HD204_Last_Detection.TagCode
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Mayfield_HD102_First_Last_Detections 
           ON  dbo.Characteristics.TagCode = dbo.Mayfield_HD102_First_Last_Detections.TagCode
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Hatchery_First_Last_Detections
           ON dbo.Characteristics.TagCode = dbo.Hatchery_First_Last_Detections.TagCode
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Mayfield_HD101_First_Last_Detections
           ON dbo.Characteristics.TagCode = dbo.Mayfield_HD101_First_Last_Detections.TagCode
  WHERE      (NOT (dbo.Characteristics.FishStatus LIKE N'mort'))
    AND (dbo.Characteristics.DNCO IS NULL)
    AND (dbo.Characteristics.Upstream IS NULL)
```

Thank you for any help you can give me!!

Addition!
I've gotten a little closer but run into an issue.  If I don't put the a.[Date/Time] in the Group by I get the following error: Column 'a.Date/Time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  But if I put the a.[Date/Time] I get all the date times instead of just the min/max for HD=101.

```
Select
    c.TagCode,
    c.Release,
    c.[Release Date/Time],
    MIN (CASE a.HD WHEN 101 THEN a.[Date/Time]ELSE Null END) AS HD101_First_Detection,
    datediff(second, c.[Release Date/Time],  a.[Date/Time]) AS TravelTime_101,
    MAX (CASE a.HD WHEN 101 THEN a.[Date/Time]ELSE Null END) AS HD101_Last_Detection,
    c.FishStatus,
    c.DNCO,
    c.Upstream,
    c.Tagger
From
    dbo.All_data a
        inner join
    dbo.Characteristics c
        on a.Tagcode = c.TagCode
Where
    HD In (101) And
    Not c.FishStatus like N'mort' And
    c.DNCO is null and 
    c.Upstream is null
Group By
    c.TagCode,
    c.Release,
    c.[Release Date/Time],
    c.FishStatus,
    c.DNCO,
    c.Upstream,
    c.Tagger,
    a.[Date/Time]
```

Comment: Been a long time since I've used Access, but I think you need to change `having dbo.All_data.HD = 101` to `where dbo.All_data.HD = 101' (and move it before the group by). That having clause won't be applied until after the rest of the query has been processed. So it will spin through all the rows every single time, then strip out the ones that don't match the having.

Comment: You have a 30 million row table in Microsoft Access??!!!

Comment: I'm thinking (hoping!) that Access is the front end to a SQL Server db.

Comment: Please clarify what database this is. Since you have 'dbo' in it I guess it's SQL Server.

Comment: The table is in SQL Server 2008 using Access in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might be able to combine some of your queries. Assuming the first query is an example of the Mayfield view then you can combine the first four like (probably syntax errors):

```
Select
    c.TagCode,
    c.Release,
    c.[Release Date/Time],
    min(IIf(a.HD = 101, a.[Date/Time], Null)) AS HD101_First_Detection,
    datediff(second, c.[Release Date/Time], min(IIf(a.HD = 101, a.[Date/Time], Null)) as TravelTime_101,
    max(IIf(a.HD = 101, a.[Date/Time], Null)) AS HD101_Last_Detection,
    min(IIf(a.HD = 102, a.[Date/Time], Null)) AS HD102_First_Detection,
    datediff(second, c.[Release Date/Time], min(IIf(a.HD = 102, a.[Date/Time], Null)) as TravelTime_102,
    max(IIf(a.HD = 102, a.[Date/Time], Null)) AS HD102_Last_Detection,
    min(IIf(a.HD = 203, a.[Date/Time], Null)) AS HD102_First_Detection,
    datediff(second, c.[Release Date/Time], min(IIf(a.HD = 203, a.[Date/Time], Null)) as TravelTime_203,
    max(IIf(a.HD = 203, a.[Date/Time], Null)) AS HD102_Last_Detection,
    min(IIf(a.HD = 204, a.[Date/Time], Null)) AS HD204_First_Detection,
    datediff(second, c.[Release Date/Time], min(IIf(a.HD = 204, a.[Date/Time], Null)) as TravelTime_204,
    max(IIf(a.HD = 204, a.[Date/Time], Null)) AS HD204_Last_Detection,
    c.FishStatus,
    c.DNCO,
    c.Upstream,
    c.Tagger
From
    dbo.All_data a
        inner join
    dbo.Characteristics c
        on a.Tagcode = c.TagCode
Where
    HD In (101, 102, 203, 204) And
    Not c.FishStatus like N'mort' And
    c.DNCO is null and 
    c.Upstream is null
Group By
    c.TagCode,
    c.Release,
    c.[Release Date/Time],
    c.FishStatus,
    c.DNCO,
    c.Upstream,
    c.Tagger
```

An index on `All_data (TagCode, HD, [Date/Time])` should help with this.

Comment: I put an index on what you suggested and that made a huge difference.  10 minutes instead of 3 hours.  Thank You!!